# Mule Anypoint Studio debugger not stopping at breakpoint in subflow

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

I'm learning how to use Mule Anypoint Studio and am finding the Debugger to be very helpful.  I'm running Anypoint Studio 6.2.2 and using ESB 3.8.3 EE.  Debugging works fine when my breakpoints are in the main flow, but if I add a "Flow Reference Component" to a subflow and add breakpoints to the subflow, the application doesn't stop at these breakpoints (in the subflow) during Debugging.  Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Restart your anypoint studio and try again.
Cheers!

Comment: That was easy.  Thanks!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Process thread get stuck sometime and will not able to recognize breakpoints, so It will good to restart Anypoint studio and refresh project once.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you really have a condition that is taking your flow into the sub flow. It is possible that your main flow is either stopping or throwing exception, hence the flow may not reaching to the flow at all. I think this is more probable reason of why debugger is not taking into subflow. Please add a logger at sub flow and just run in normal mode to see if you are actually going to subflow.

Answer (score 0):

Attempting to restart Anypoint Studio didn't work for me.
Cleaning the project and changing workspaces didn't do it either.

What resolved it was deleting the project (Without removing from disk) changing to a new workspace when restarting mule and re-importing the project from scratch.